# Why is the ResponseEntity always null using RestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, null, resttemplate

I want to do a `postForEntity` but the result is always null. What can the reason?

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> updateContactProperty(final Long contactId, final String json) throws RestClientException {

    ResponseEntity<Void> crmResponse = null;
    try {
        crmResponse = crmRestTemplate.postForEntity(
                "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/400000001/profile?hapikey=myApiKey", json, Void.class);
    }  catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (RestClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Error r) {
        r.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    return crmResponse;
}
```

I tried `ResponseEntity<Void>`, `ResponseEntity<Object>`, `ResponseEntity<String>`.

The MessageConverters registered with RestTemplate:

1. ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
2. StringHttpMessageConverter
3. ResourceHttpMessageConverter
4. SourceHttpMessageConverter
5. AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
6. Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter
7. MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

No exception can be caught...the call is just conducted but nothing happens.

Comment: No, that seems to be different.

Comment: `Object.class` instead of  `Void.class`

Comment: As you can see in my question I already tried with ResponseEntity<Void>, ResponseEntity<Object>, ResponseEntity<String>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the requested API responds with a `HttpStatusCodeException` and an empty body. `HttpStatusCodeException` is derived from `RestClientException` and because I caught the `RestClientException` first, it was already consumed and furthermore I didn't populated the exception to the caller of my `updateContactProperty(...)` method after catching it so that the caller never noticed that a response (or exception respectively) returned.